# How to create and validate Docker signed manifests

Tags: docker

How exactly is expected to be created and validated signed manifest for a Docker container using schema v1?

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-1/#signed-manifests) shows an example of a signed manifest file, like the one shown below:

```
{
   "name": "hello-world",
   "tag": "latest",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
      }
   ],
   "history": [
      {
         "v1Compatibility": ".."
      }
   ],
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "signatures": [
      {
         "header": {
            "jwk": {
               "crv": "P-256",
               "kid": "OD6I:6DRK:JXEJ:KBM4:255X:NSAA:MUSF:E4VM:ZI6W:CUN2:L4Z6:LSF4",
               "kty": "EC",
               "x": "3gAwX48IQ5oaYQAYSxor6rYYc_6yjuLCjtQ9LUakg4A",
               "y": "t72ge6kIA1XOjqjVoEOiPPAURltJFBMGDSQvEGVB010"
            },
            "alg": "ES256"
         },
         "signature": "XREm0L8WNn27Ga_iE_vRnTxVMhhYY0Zst_FfkKopg6gWSoTOZTuW4rK0fg_IqnKkEKlbD83tD46LKEGi5aIVFg",
         "protected": "eyJmb3JtYXRMZW5ndGgiOjY2MjgsImZvcm1hdFRhaWwiOiJDbjAiLCJ0aW1lIjoiMjAxNS0wNC0wOFQxODo1Mjo1OVoifQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

It's mentioned that the signature can be generated using *trustlib*, however, it's not clear how. Is there any code example or even better a CLI tool that can be used to sign and validate a manifest as the one above?

Comment: Those have been deprecated, and the solution that followed (notary v1 / content trust) will likely be deprecated soon. I'd recommend looking at sigstore/cosign (or the still being designed notary v2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my need is related to the support for legacy containers. Is there anything out there?

Comment: Last time this was touched was 6 years ago, no idea if there are any examples out there, may need the Internet archive. https://github.com/docker/libtrust